# Is websocket connection reliable?

Tags: java, websocket

I always thought that web socket guarantees delivery of data as it is built on top of TCP which is reliable. I was reading the Java web socket API documentation on this link
https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/websocket/RemoteEndpoint.html
It says that

> There is no guarantee of the successful delivery of a web socket message to the peer, but if the action of sending a message causes an error known to the container, the API throws it.

Shouldn't TCP gurantee the message delivery?

Comment: Web socket is an abstraction over TCP. In other words Web Socket protocol 's underlying protocol is TCP(Web socket messages are transferred over TCP). Just like HTTP protocol is used on top of TCP.  Web Socket implementations have their own packet or frames which may have additional guarantees such as message ordering based on correlation ids. Since connection between client and server can be broken at any time, any messages failed need to be resent without any intervention from either side.  This may help you understand this distinction

Comment: TCP does not guarantee message delivery.  It has built-in means of detecting transmission errors or packet corruption and attempting retransmissions in those cases, but delivery can still fail.  It guarantees that if the packet is not delivered, the caller will get an error so the caller can know.  Since websocket is built on top of TCP, it has the same issue.  There may ultimately be a delivery error if the network connection is broken.

Comment: @Bunti So will packet be retransmitted during packet loss while using websocket?

Comment: @jfriend00     But TCP retransmits packet during packet loss, right?

Comment: @Tejas  - Yes, if the packet is just lost, but the connection is working.  But once the connection is truly broken, TCP will eventually give up and return an error.  So, TCP guarantees reliable delivery when the connection is working, but can't guarantee that the connection stays working.  Imagine you're communicating with a mobile device and the mobile goes out of coverage.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Reliable != Guaranteed. Reliable means you'll be notified if there was a failure (or success) - if the end users unplugs their lan cable, even tcp can't 'guarantee delivery.'

Comment: But is the packet retransmitted when packet loss occurs?

Comment: For tcp, yes - this is handled by the OS's implementation of tcp, and your app (the application layer) wouldn't be notified until success/failure.

Answer (score 9):

"Guarantee" is a bit misleading.  TCP will make a best attempt to send ordered data sent by one TCP stack to be received in-order by another TCP stack.  If this cannot be done, the TCP stacks will engage in an error situation.  This is no different than a money-back guarantee you get from a store; failure mode means you get a replacement and try again... eventually if too many failures and get your money back (e.g., connection broken).

Also... a TCP "guarantee" does *not* mean the data is "guaranteed" to be handled correctly at the application levels of both stacks.  This is the responsibility of application protocols.  After its work is done, TCP hands it off to the application layers above it which implement things like pub/sub, http, rpc, tuple spaces, email, ftp, transactions, databases, etc, etc...